# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to set a state. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Cart = (props) => {

    const [useCart, setCart] = useState([]);
        
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const result = await axios
                .get('https://example.com/sample')
                .then((res) => {
                    setCart(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        })();
    }, []);

    console.log(useCart);

    return (
        <div></div>
    );

}

export default Cart;
```

The API returns value like that:

```
[
    {
        'id': 5,
        'qwe': 'qwe',
        'asd': [
            {
                'aaa': 'aaa',
                'bbb': 'bbb'
            }
        ],
        'zxc': 'zxc'
    },
    {
        'id': 7,
        'qwe': 'qwe',
        'asd': [
            {
                'aaa': 'aaa',
                'bbb': 'bbb'
            }
        ],
        'zxc': 'zxc'
    }
]
```

I'm not rendering this on component. I'm just trying to console log it. But it give error like that:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, qwe, asd, zxc}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I couldn't understand, where do I do wrong.

Comment: Can you add complete component code?

Comment: how are you using `useCart`?

Comment: @MattAft I'm trying to console log it

Comment: @ShubhamVerma ok, editing the question now

Comment: @ShubhamVerma edited the question

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code, are you sure this is what you have?

Comment: Can you confirm if `res.data` returns array not object? Other than that I don't see any issue in logging the response.

Comment: Agree with @MattAft you are rendering an empty `div` so there shouldn't be any part of that response object getting rendered, according to your shared snippet. Are you sure the snippet is an accurate representation of the code causing issue?

Comment: @sundowatch There is something missing. Can you add it to codesandbox?

Comment: I doubt your render method is empty like that, can you share your jsx

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's going wrong with your code but maybe I can help you debug it. I copied your API's response to a file and simply imported it inside the component to a variable. I then set the state to that variable and everything works fine, all console logs and everything. Check it out here-

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-ramanujan-3k97v?file=/src/App.js

That tells me the problem could be coming from your `useEffect` where you are handling your API response.

One change that I made and I think you should do it too when you logout a state variable you should do it inside a lifecycle hook. So you should put your `console.log(useCart);` inside this
 `useEffect(()=>{ console.log(useCart); },[useCart])`